# After hijacking OnAuthRequired event on Chrome (via extension), how do I return back to the browser to seek auth from user?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I am trying to auto-login a certain site, by doing the following

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(function(){..});
```

But suppose the auth fails, how do I escape out of the lambda and tell the browser we give up, please seek auth from the user?

What happens now is that if I return, it just say "Waiting for extension blabla.." on the status bar.

Comment: Did you use 'asyncBlocking'?

Answer (score 1):

You should use asyncBlocking and call callback without parameters if you can't provide auth details.

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
  function(details, callback) {
    if (everything is fine) {
      callback({authCredentials: {username: email, password: password}});
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }, 
  {urls: ["<your urls>"]},
  ["asyncBlocking"]
);
```